# How to export grease pencil to svg?

Tags: export, grease-pencil, svg

Is there a way to export a GreasePencil object to a `.svg` file?

I am looking for a way to export it directly through Blender, hopefully without any third-party add-ons.

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMm0KeMJsI4) tutorial by blender, they have given that the .svg can be exported through `File>Export>GreasePencil`.
But, in my version of Blender, I am not able to find these options...I only have these:

[image]

Also, I have the latest version of Blender (2.92)

Comment: See the manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.92/addons/render/render_freestyle_svg.html?highlight=render%20freestyle

Comment: There are also new export options available in latest builds: https://developer.blender.org/D10482

Comment: @brockmann, yes, using that addon is one of the possibilities....but it does not export coloured tints...

Comment: @brockmann, also, I am unable to find the new *Export Options* of `SVG`, they are neither in the `File>Export` nor `Output Properties>Output>File Format`

Comment: Recommend edit your question and add that you'd like to transfer the colors over as well. Re the new export options: try one of the latest builds: https://builder.blender.org/download/

Answer (score 2):

The svg export only works in object mode. Switch into object mode and you should see it.
However, the documentation for 2.92 doesn't seem to have a page for this, so you should probably use 2.93 or higher.